# Writing Continuous data to a file in VC++ 2008

Tags: visual-c++, fwrite

I want to write a multiple value to a file whenever I provide a new one. In other words, I have a program which continuously gets the user data until I give exit and I need to write it to a file .But , What the problem is I am getting the last data I entered only.

Kindly give me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO doesn't work that way, you need to provide some attempts and ask something concerning your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You want to append to a file, rather than overwrite its contents. There are several APIs to deal with files in C++, this example is only one of many ways:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2344/

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fstream filestr;

    filestr.open ("file.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);

    filestr<<"YAY"<<endl;   

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```